# 1 out of 3 Transactions in DB2 fail with SQL 998, State 58005, error code 8, sub code 2

Tags: db2, configuration, db2-luw, db2-10.5

We have a few back-end applications using an XA switch module connected to a DB2 (10.5).
2 or 3 transactions will pass until this shows up:
[image]

I’ve found [this document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00998n.html) that talks about “Code 998, state 58005, reason code 9, subcode 2". 
Unfortunately, all they say is:

> For reason code 9, subcode 02, ensure that the tp_mon_name configuration parameter contains the name of the dynamic library in the external product which has the ax_reg() function used for dynamic registration of transactions.

1. On the other hand, I found [this document](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.2pc.doc/doc/c0005106.html) where, on the explanation of `tm_database`, they say "don't use tp_mon_name, if you are using XA switch module", which I am. But they don't explain `tm_database`.
2. I have two versions of the switch module, one with `CONSTANT DYNAMICREGISTRATION "Y"` and one with `CONSTANT DYNAMICREGISTRATION "N"`.
   The latter exists somewhere and will take me huge time to find.
   Do you think it could be it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this was the switch module. 
The `RM OPEN STRING` definition included: `rmopenstring=db=mydatabase,uid=uuuuuu,pwd=pppp,,axlib=somelib`
Once the value for `axlib` was supplemented with an extention, `.so`, the error has gone away.

Comment: You should accept the answer so that others easily can see what the solution was.

Comment: @Lennart, sure! I just thought a better answer might show up

Comment: @mustaccio, thanks for the editing work!